# vb.net webbrowser get value human verify

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, browser, webbrowser-control, captcha

Please check this picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPJHE.jpg

website link:

http://tehparadox.com/forum/newthread.php?do=newthread&f=43
you can login:
user : bestpal
pass : qwerty
this is just a random website with the same function

what I'm trying to do is, I'm trying to popout the "RANDOM QUESTION" as i did with the captcha(left side picture), but the "RANDOM QUESTION"(right side picture) doesn't have an ID I can get to Pop it out on my program.

is there anyway i could do to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Given the html of the page in your example:

```
...
<label for="humanverify">Please type "Google" in the answer area, without quotations.</label>
...
```

You can search for the `<label>` element where its "for" attribute is equal to "humanverify", using LINQ and the HTMLDocument from the WebBrowser instance:

```
Dim htmlDocument = webBrowser1.Document
Dim element = htmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("label").Cast(Of HtmlElement)().FirstOrDefault(Function(e) e.GetAttribute("for") = "humanverify")

If element IsNot Nothing Then
    Return element.InnerText
End If
```

Not tested code (just converted a sketch in C#), but it works for me in most of cases. Hope it helps.